# js - wrong value of floated elements' offsetLeft

Tags: javascript, css-float, offset

I have a wrapper which is 100% wide and has hidden overflow and another div in it which has fixed height and width equal to the sum of it's children's width.
Each child is floated left and all of them should fit perfectly in their parent but I'm not getting the offsetLeft values I think I should have been getting.

The width of the container is calculated (correctly) like this:

```
items_width = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    items_width += items[i].clientWidth;
}
```

and yet this function:

```
function setOffsets(){
    for(var j = 0; j < items.length; j++){
        items_offset.push(items[j].offsetLeft);
    }
    return items_offset;
}
```

returns this array:

> [0, 470, 790, 1259, 1730, 0, 220, 773, 1243, 1737, 1957, 0]

The way I see it, some of the items are wrapped into another line - although if I set the container's left margin to, let's say, -1500px, the further items are properly floated.

I really am curious why the offset seems broken and is it possible to overwrite this behaviour?

The problem occurs on both Firefox 47.0 and Chrome 51.0